# Why PRAM and not PROM?

Tags: memory-management, memory-hardware

I read:

> NVRAM is the updated Mac terminology for PRAM and is short for
> Non-Volatile RAM.

Plus, I know that there are 2 types of main memory RAM and ROM while the first is Volatile the second isn't.

So, my question is, **why it was called NVRAM/PRAM and not NVROM/PROM?**

Comment: To my understanding (and I don't really know a lot about this kind of things), ROM is "Read Only Memory" (for storing BIOS programs for example) while RAM is general purpose (it can be written and read from). So a non-volatile RAM isn't quite a ROM

Comment: Because it's not read-only?